# stop mootools Drag.Move reducing objects to top left

Tags: drag-and-drop, mootools, mootools-more

I am trying to create a UI whereby objects can be moved between two buckets.  I am already invested in Mootools and such functionality appears to be available.  However, when I instantiate a `Drag.Move` object on my draggable objects, it changes their `position` to `absolute` but doesn't seem to set their absolute position to honour their original position.

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BloodBaz/e77pchbk/)

Comment: Latest Google Chrome (40.0.2214.115).
In IE11, the situation is worse - the X-Z objects are all over to the left overlaying the A-D objects.

Comment: If you want to see my intended "initial state" then simply untick "Mootools More 1.5.0" from the Frameworks and Extensions panel and rerun.

Comment: Would this work for you? -> http://jsfiddle.net/e77pchbk/1/

Comment: Thanks Sergio!  Yes it would.  The only change you've added is to include the CSS rules `position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;` to the drag objects although I am a little last as to how to fixes things.  If you add an explanation as an "Answer" I'll tick it off for you. Thanks